# Shell utility does not work in perl system() call

Tags: perl, powershell

I have a Perl script in which I would like to use system() to call some shell programs and possibly postprocess the output of the programs on the fly.

From within the powershell, I can run more, tee, grep and other stuff without specifiying the full path to the executables.
I do not understand why the following fails

```
C:\Users\xxxwork> perl -W -e "system 'more foo.log | tee  bar.txt'"
'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

while the following works,
     C:\Users\xxxwork> perl -W -e "system 'more foo.log | grep -e failed'"

A direct call to tee works

```
C:\Users\xxxwork> tee
cmdlet Tee-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
FilePath:
```

I have tried replacing tee by it's full from "Tee-Object" but I get the same result. Is there any extra environement variable that needs to be set in this particular case for Perl to see the full $Path as seen by the shell?
Is this simply because in one case grep is a pure application and in the other case tee is shell utility?

```
PS C:\Users\xxxwork>  get-command Tee-Object

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Cmdlet          Tee-Object                                         Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility 
PS C:\Users\xxxwork> get-command grep

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName
-----------     ----                                               ----------
Application     grep.exe
```

Thanks
G

Comment: What is a "shell utility"? `system` runs `cmd.exe`, not Powershell.

Comment: What @choroba said. Besides, what are you trying to achieve anyway? It's utterly pointless to run `more`/`tee` inside Perl inside PowerShell. Both Perl and PowerShell are perfectly capable of doing virtually anything you could do with shell commands, and you absolutely don't need both.

Comment: It seems that this is the real problem **system()** runs **cmd.exe** and not the **Powershell**. Is there an easy way to force **system()** to use **Powershell**? I have tried `system("powershell 'mycommands'")` but it does now work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system` has two purposes. It can used to launch a program:

```
system($program, @args_to_program)
```

Or it can be used to execute a shell command:

```
system($shell_command)
```

The latter is basically equivalent to

```
system('cmd', '/x', '/c', $shell_command)
```

From `powershell /?`, we see it can be instructed to execute a command using the `-Command` argument, so the equivalent for `powershell` would be

```
system('powershell', '-Command', $powershell_command)
```

Comment: As an alternative setting the env variable PERL5SHELL to something like `$env:PERL5SHELL="powershell -Command"`
(for instance by adding the line above in **$profile**) also does the job. In my case however (with both variants), although the execution policy is set to **RemoteSigned**, the shell complains that **$profile cannot be loaded because script execution is disabled on the machine**. Nevertheless, the commands are executed as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't recomment that. I can't really think of a use case where it makes sense to use PERL5SHELL to specify a different shell. PERL5SHELL should be used to provide the path to the expected shell (cmd or sh), and maybe options.

Comment: IMHO using PERL5SHELL makes the script more portable since it could be run on another system without further modification.

Comment: No, you have it backwards. The approach I used will make it work on all systems. The way you suggested requires users of your script to change the env var first. Furthermore, they can't make that change to the environment of any other process other than your script (since it will break their other scripts), so they'll have to write a script that wraps your script to set the env var. That's getting crazy, just to avoid specifying you need powershell when you need powershell.